# Simultaneous working with Excel in SP2010

Tags: 2010, excel, versioning, co-authoring

Is it possible to work with multiple users simultaneous on the same excel document in SP2010?
If possible without the excel web app.

Extra... Is it possible to work with different versions then?

What is necessary to let this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this... So I guess it won't work :(

> Unlike Word, PowerPoint and OneNote 2010 it’s not possible to have
>   multiple authors working on a document at the same time in Microsoft
>   Excel 2010. However, if you have access to the Office Web Applications
>   – where it is possible to edit Word, PowerPoint and Excel documents
>   via a browser – there is an alternative available.
>
> The Excel Web Application has a feature known as Collaborative Editing
>   – which is basically the co-authoring offered in Word, PowerPoint and
>   OneNote – allowing multiple authors to work on a spreadsheet at the
>   same time. Unlike co-authoring in the client, edits by other users
>   working on the document are not applied when the document is saved,
>   rather the document is updated as the changes are made.